# Contact Address Format

Tags: visualforce-template

I am using the below `Visualforce Email Template`:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Address Allignment" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Contact">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >

    <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!IF(len(relatedTo.MailingCity)>0, true , false)}">   
        <apex:outputfield value="{!relatedTo.MailingCity}"/> ,
    </apex:outputpanel>   

    <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!IF(len(relatedTo.MailingState)>0, true , false)}">   
        <apex:outputfield value="{!relatedTo.MailingState}"/> ,
    </apex:outputpanel>      

    <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!IF(len(relatedTo.MailingCountry)>0, true , false)}">   
        <apex:outputfield value="{!relatedTo.MailingCountry}"/> ,
    </apex:outputpanel>   

    <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!IF(len(relatedTo.MailingPostalCode)>0, true , false)}">   
        <apex:outputfield value="{!relatedTo.MailingPostalCode}"/>.
    </apex:outputpanel>      

    <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!IF(len(relatedTo.MailingStreet)>0, true , false)}">   
        <apex:outputfield value="{!relatedTo.MailingStreet}"/>.
    </apex:outputpanel>   <br/>    

</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Output:

> Bangalore ,Karnataka ,India ,560066,Marathahalli. If we specify all address fields

If i specify only State value like Karnataka then the output looks like:

> Karnataka ,

Now my requirement is not to include comma(,) after State value.

Comment: Note that you can always replace `IF(condition, true, false)` with simply `condition`...

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
<apex:outputpanel rendered="{!IF(len(relatedTo.MailingCity)>0, true , false)}">   
        <apex:outputfield value="{!relatedTo.MailingCity}"/> 
    </apex:outputpanel>  
<apex:outputpanel rendered="{!len(relatedTo.MailingState)>0 && len(relatedTo.MailingCity)>0}">   
         ,
    </apex:outputpanel>  

    <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!IF(len(relatedTo.MailingState)>0, true , false)}">   
        <apex:outputfield value="{!relatedTo.MailingState}"/> 
    </apex:outputpanel>
```

Use one extra panel for `,` and you will get expected output. You need to make same set of condition for all next comma.

**Update** you can also do one more thing here.

```
<apex:outputpanel rendered="{!IF(len(relatedTo.MailingCity)>0, true , false)}">   
            <apex:outputfield value="{!relatedTo.MailingCity}"/> ,
        </apex:outputpanel>  
        <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!IF(len(relatedTo.MailingState)>0, true , false)}">   
            <apex:outputfield value="{!relatedTo.MailingState}"/> ,
        </apex:outputpanel>
```

then use some JavaScript to remove comma from end

```
var lastChar = myString[myString.length -1];
if(lastChar == ',')
 myString = myString.slice(0, -1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! As my requirement is all the address field values are separated with commas (,).
like Bangalore ,Karnataka ,India ,560066,Marathahalli.

if we provide any values like city or state or country or pincode and the values will display with separated by commas only. like
city,state,county,pin,area.
if we specify city,area then o/p is city,area.
if we specify city,country and pin then o/p:city,county,pin

Comment: @RaviKumar yes you need to use separate render condition for this to handle also check my updated answer.